# My motherboard's power supply connector is 20 pin, but all the power supplies I see for sale are 20+4 pin. Can this work?

Tags: power-supply, power, desktop-computer, connector

I just got one on newegg that is 20+4 pin, but I need 20 pin.  I thought since it says 20+4 instead of 24 that I might still be able to use it for a 20 pin connector?  Or is there a converter I can get?  It looks like 4 of the pins can be detached at one end.  Is that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally that is what 20+4 pin means, it can work with either 20 or 24 pin socket on the motherboard.

Some of the 24 pin connectors you can slide off or unclip 4 from one end, its hard to see sometimes, look close. When you buy a new 20+4 PSU sometimes they are joined already sometimes not.

If you get a 24 pin only, use an [Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001D2LU08) (Example link only, they can be bought cheaper other places)

.

[image]